# What does dataoffset do?

Tags: solidity, assembly, yul

in the [doc](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/yul.html?highlight=dataoffset#datasize-dataoffset-datacopy) it says:

... Can only take string literals (the names of other objects) as arguments and return the size and offset in the data area

but I'm still confused, could anybody give me an example of how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the following dummy smart contract written in Yul :

```
object "ExampleContract" {
  code {
    datacopy(0, dataoffset("Runtime"), datasize("Runtime"))
    return(0, datasize("Runtime"))
  }
  object "Runtime" {
    code {
      return(0x0, 0x0)
    }
  }
}
```

You can compile it with :

```sh
solc --strict-assembly .\contract.yul
```

This part is the deployment code :

```
code {
    datacopy(0, dataoffset("Runtime"), datasize("Runtime"))
    return(0, datasize("Runtime"))
  }
```

Whose role is to copy and return the runtime code defined here :

```
 object "Runtime" {
    code {
      return(0x0, 0x0)
    }
  }
```

This is where you see the most common example of `datacopy`, `dataoffset` and `datasize` : when the deployement bytecode copies and returns the runtime bytecode.

`dataoffset("Runtime")` and `datasize("Runtime")` will be replaced by the offset and size of the "Runtime" object in the **compiled bytecode**. That is, by where is the runtime bytecode is located, and how long it is respectively.

So that `datacopy(0, dataoffset("Runtime"), datasize("Runtime"))` can copy a well-defined section of the code (with a starting point and a length) so that it can be returned on the next line, deploying the runtime code to the blockchain.

Those are just a practical way to refer to property / characteristics of sections (*i.e.,* objects)  of the compiled code before compilation if that makes sense.

I hope that answers your question.